# Duplicate files uploading in Python Selenium send_keys() method

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

```
pdfs =[file1, file2, file3]
uploadButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
for i in range(len(pdfs)):
   uploadButton.send_keys(pdfs[i])
```

The above code I am using for uploading multiple files using send_keys() in ChromeDriver.
Here it will work fine in the 1st iteration in the 2nd iteration it will upload 2 files and in 3rd iteration uploads 3 files. In every iteration duplicate files are uploading.
I need a solution to upload one by one file using for loop without duplication.
I know we can upload all files at one time like this

```
files = file1 + '\n' + file2 + '\n' + file3
uploadButton.send_keys(files)
```

But I don't wants to upload all files at once I have to upload one by one in using for loop.
Can anyone help me out of this problem using Python + Selenium.

Comment: click on upload button in every iteration of the for loop

Comment: If I click filedialogue box will open to slelect files.

Comment: I mean you will have to submit the file once its uploading finishes then again you have to continue next iteration

Comment: I have to upload all files and then I have to submit, I can't submit one by one files

Comment: Dont take the length of the list instead directly try as `for item in pdfs:    uploadButton.send_keys(item)`

Comment: like this also causing the same problem uploading duplicate files

Comment: Without looking at your functionality its difficult to address with such minimal information.

Comment: What information you need? @Dev

Answer (score 0):

If your input doesn't allow multiple files, then this is not possible. You would have to select file1, upload and then go back to the page and repeat the process for each file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring your webelement within each iteration?

Like this?

```
pdfs =[file1, file2, file3]

for i in range(len(pdfs)):
    uploadButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
    uploadButton.send_keys(pdfs[i])
```

Comment: Yes I tried this method also same thing duplicate files uploading

Answer (score 0):

Use **clear()** method to clear the input every time before sending the path.
your code should look like this:

```
pdfs =[file1, file2, file3]
uploadButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
for i in range(len(pdfs)):
   uploadButton.clear() # Add this line to clear the input
   uploadButton.send_keys(pdfs[i])
```