# Selenium: trying to upload two files but three or more files have been uploaded

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

I tried to add photo to Facebook marketplace in [here](https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/create/item) with selenium python like this:
`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="file"]').send_keys('C:/image.jpg')`
when I try to send one photo, one photo have been sent, the problem is when I try to send two or more photo like this:

```
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/create/item')
for ko in range(0, 2):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="file"]').send_keys('C:/img_from_url.jpg')
```

three photos have been sent, I don't know where is the problem, so i want where I send two photo, only two photo have been sent, this is my simple code, please help me, any answer will be appreciated

Comment: Please share all your code. Currently your question missing basic details

Comment: @Prophet this is my code for input file, only it, i try to send two photo but three photos have been sent

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug.
When uploading a file with a `send_keys()` method in a loop the file is being uploaded twice.
I.e. if you performing send keys 2 times the file file be uploaded 4 time, for 3 iterations 6 files will be uploaded etc.
Currently I see no solution for this issue. F.e. adding a delay inside the loop doesn't resolve it.
I see similar question [was already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71154814/duplicate-files-uploading-in-python-selenium-send-keys-method) but no solution was given there too.

Comment: thanks for your answers, i found a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066430/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-sendkeys-selenium) with `\n` to add multiple files